# When to phlebotomize in Eisenmenger syndrome?

Tags: heart-disease

Secondary erythrocytosis occurs in Eisenmenger syndrome as opposed to polycythaemia. Haemoglobin levels can be quite high and levels such as 22 g/L are common.

Phlebotomy is commonly used to treat polycythemia, and to treat the hyperviscosity.  So, is there a role for this in the secondary erythrocytosis of Eisenmenger syndrome?